# use google map places api with direction service

Tags: google-places-api

i want to mark polylines on road using the direction service , however when i use a place name in the origin paramter it returns something else
for e.g

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=candies bandra west&destination=thadomal shahani engineering college&sensor=false
```

this is my request , but what i get in response to the origin is just : Bandra West, Mumbai, 
Maharashtra, India
 i have tried other queries too, like  'carter road amphitheater bandra' but even here the response is returned as bandra west  , mumbai , maharashtra , india